# Number of poker hands where we have at least each suit once.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

The solution to the problem is C(4,1)C(13,2)C(13,1)C(13,1)C(13,1) = 685 464, but I don't understand how we got there. C(4,1) is the number of ways to choose 1 out of 4 suits, then C(13,2), ways to select 2 cards out of 13 because of the pigeon principle, but then why aren't we choosing 1 out of 3 suits afterwards for the next card and 1 out of 2 suits for the next? Why are we choosing 1 out of 4 suits only once for 5 cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a five-card poker hand contains all four suits, it must contain two cards of one of the four suits and one card each from each of the other three suits.

Choose the suit from which two cards will be drawn, which can be done in $\binom{4}{1}$ ways.

Choose two cards of that suit, which can be done in $\binom{13}{2}$.

Choose one card from each of the three remaining suits, which can be done in $\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}$ ways.

Applying the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) yields
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{13}{2}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}$$
five-card poker hands in which each suit appears at least once.

Comment: why aren't we choosing the suits for each of the three remaining cards?

Comment: Once we have determined the suit from which we will draw two cards, we must draw one card from each of the other suits.  Therefore, we do not need to choose those suits. What we need to do is choose which card we will draw from each of those suits.